# Understanding reference count in python

Tags: python, garbage-collection, reference-counting

I'm trying to understand how reference count work in python. I created a variable x and assigned a value of 10 to it. So basically x is pointing to the memory location where object of class int (10) is stored. Now when I try to get reference count of x and 10, I get two different reference counts. If x is pointing to the same memory location where 10 is stored then why do they have different reference counts?

```py
>>> import sys
>>> sys.getrefcount(10)
12
>>> a = 10
>>> sys.getrefcount(10)
13
>>> sys.getrefcount(a)
11
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you directly call `sys.getrefcount(10)` the call itself increases the reference count. There's one reference for `10` at the call site, and at least one more for reasons I can't exactly recall.

More detailed answer: When you run a statement in the interactive prompt, that statement is compiled into bytecode, which is then exec'd by the interpreter.  The bytecode is stored in a `code` object, which you can inspect by compiling a statement yourself with the [`compile()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#compile) builtin:

```py
>>> a = 10
>>> c = compile('sys.getrefcount(10)', '<stdin>', 'single')
>>> c
<code object <module> at 0x7f4def343270, file "<stdin>", line 1>
```

We can use the `dis` module to inspect the compiled bytecode:

```py
>>> dis.dis(c)
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (sys)
              2 LOAD_ATTR                1 (getrefcount)
              4 LOAD_CONST               0 (10)
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              8 PRINT_EXPR
             10 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
             12 RETURN_VALUE
```

You can see before `CALL_FUNCTION` is the byte code `LOAD_CONST 10`.  But how does it know `10` is the constant to load?  The actual bytecode instruction is `LOAD_CONST(0)` where `0` is an index into a table of constants which is stored in the `code` object:

```
>>> c.co_consts
(10, None)
```

So this is where one of the new references to `10` lives (temporarily).

Whereas if we do:

```py
>>> c2 = compile('sys.getrefcount(a)', '<stdin>', 'single')
>>> dis.dis(c2)
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (sys)
              2 LOAD_ATTR                1 (getrefcount)
              4 LOAD_NAME                2 (a)
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              8 PRINT_EXPR
             10 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             12 RETURN_VALUE
```

Instead of `LOAD_CONST` there's just `LOAD_NAME` of whatever `a` happens to point to.  The object `10` itself is not referenced anywhere in the `code` object.

**Update:** The source of the second reference is pretty obscure, but it comes from the AST parser which uses an [Arena](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Python/pyarena.c) structure for efficient memory management of AST nodes and the like.  The arena also maintains a list (as in an actual Python `list`) of Python objects parsed in the AST, in the case of numbers that happens here: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/fee96422e6f0056561cf74fef2012cc066c9db86/Python/ast.c#L2144 (where `PyArena_AddPyObject` adds the object to said list).  IIUC this list exists just to ensure that literals parsed from the AST have at least one reference held somewhere.

In the actual C code for compiling and running interactive statements the arena isn't freed [until after the compiled statement has been executed](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/fee96422e6f0056561cf74fef2012cc066c9db86/Python/pythonrun.c#L257), at which point that second extra reference goes away.

Comment: So you mean to say that the actual reference count of 10 is 11 and it does +1 (because of function call) and +1 (due to some other reason). But then when I call getrefcount(a), it should do 11 + 1(function call) and return 12 right? why is it returning 11?

Comment: Because in the case of `a` the compiled bytecode is just loading it from a global variable. I'll follow-up with a more detailed answer to clarify this.

Comment: The extra reference you're missing is the one loaded onto the stack by `LOAD_CONST`.

Comment: Wait, no, that's not it - that reference exists, but the `sys.getrefcount(a)` call also loads such a reference, so it's not a difference between the two calls.

Comment: Exactly, the difference between the `a` and `10` cases should be 1 not 2, since both are loaded on the stack in any case.  Interestingly if you run `exec(c)` you just get 1 more (the reference already living in the `code` object referenced by `c`).

Comment: IIRC the tokenizer and compiler create some extra references, which live long enough to be picked up by the `sys.getrefcount` call if you directly run the statement interactively, but not if you run it most other ways you could run it. I never managed to track down where all those references were coming from, and the code has been changed a number of times. You'll see some interesting data structures if you look through the output for `gc.get_referrers(10)`.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I was thinking that as well.  It could be some temporary reference from the tokenizer or the AST that hangs around just long enough in that case, which wouldn't exist in the case of an arbitrary name like  `a`.

Comment: I found where it comes from--pretty obscure.